Interesting IZHO functional equation problem
Does there exist a surjective function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
$f(f(x))=(x-1)f(x)+2$.
I was not able to finish the problem,but,I've got some good results.It wants surjective,so there exists some $a$ that $f(a)=0$.We take that $a$ and substitute with $x$.We have $f(0)=2$.If we do the same thing with $f(a)=1$,we have $f(1)=a+1$.Take $x=1$ to have $f(f(1))=2$ and take $x=0$ to get $f(2)=0$.I am stuck from this part and I don't know what would be suitable.However,I think surjectivity will play an important role.

you have already proven that $f(2)=0$ and $f(0)=2$. Since $f$ is suriective, it must exists $a$ such that $1=f(a)$. Then $f(1)=a-1+2=a+1$. Then $f(a+1)=f(f(1))=2$. Then
$0=f(2)=f(f(a+1))=2a+2$. So $a=-1$. So $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=1$. Since $f$ is suriective it must exist $b$ such that $-1=f(b)$. Then $1=f(-1)=f(f(b))=(b-1)\times-1+2=-b+3$. Hence $b=2$ so $f(2)=-1$ but $f(2)=0$, so $-1=0$ and that is not possible. So it does not exists a suriective function that is a solution of this equation.
